# xcode 5 access function from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

`UserList.m` file of viewcontroller

```
#import "UserList.h"

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)accessFromAppDelegate
{
    NSLog(@"Access from appdelegate");
}
```

in `AppDelegate.m` file i have

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        //i want access accessFromAppDelegate on UserList.m in here
    }
}
```

How to access `- (void)accessFromAppDelegate` of `UseList.m` from `AppDelegate.m`?
i using xcode 5 and will find this problem some days but can not solve. I'm new on ios developer.

Thanks for your times.

Comment: If the viewController exist when remote notification comes, you can post a custom notification with `userInfo`.

Comment: @KudoCC i will do this, but now i want if push notification comming when Application is active i want called function from viewController for add message value in `UserList` viewcontroller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare in UserList.h:

```
- (void)accessFromAppDelegate
```

Import UserList.h to AppDelegate. And call it:

```
UserList *userList = [[UserList alloc] init];
[userList accessFromAppDelegate];
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the accessFromAppDelegate is a instance method, so you must have a instance of UserList class.

```
UserList *ul = [[UserList alloc] init];
[ul accessFromAppDelegate];
```

=)

Comment: I will `#import "UserList.h"` in `AppDelegate.m` but don't work.

Comment: Thanks for your question, i will do work with answer of hoptqVN.dev